# Formula for b ... b ( b ( a ) + c ) + c) + ... c

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra

1) Let say we have a number A.

2) We multiply it by B and add C to it.

3) We repeat this action for N times.

For example for N = 3, A = 1, B = 3, C = 1, We have:
3 ( 3 ( 3 ( 1 ) + 1 ) + 1 ) + 1 ) = 40

What kind of progression do we have? Is it arithmetic or geometric? Is there any formula for the nth element or sum of the sequence until the nth element?

Answer (score 1):

Distributing all the multiplications, your expression simplifies to $B^NA + \sum_{k=0}^{N-1}B^kC$. You can prove this by induction on $N$. Except for the first term, this is a geometric series, which has closed form $$B^NA + \frac{C(1-B^N)}{(1-B)}.$$

In the simpler case that $C = A$, we really do get just a geometric series, which simplifies to $$\frac{A(1-B^{N+1})}{(1-B)}.$$

Answer (score 0):

We want to look at the recurrence,

$$x_{n+1}=bx_{n}+c \tag{1}$$

With some initial value $x_0=a$.

We may notice that there is a number $L$ such that,

$$L=bL+c \tag{2}$$

In the case $b \neq 1$, this number is $\frac{c}{1-b}$. We shall assume that, otherwise the solution is easy.

Subtracting the second equation from the first gives,

$$(x_{n+1}-L)=b(x_{n}-L)$$

So,

$$x_{n}-L=b^{n}(x_{0}-L)$$

(If your having trouble seeing this define $a_n=x_n-L$ then $a_{n+1}=ba_{n}$ etc)

Which tells us that,

$$x_{n}=L+b^{n}(a-L)$$

Or more explicitly,

$$x_{n}=\frac{c}{1-b}+b^{n}(a-\frac{c}{1-b})$$

In the case $b=1$ obviously (and simple to prove),

$$x_{n}=x_{0}+cn=a+cn$$